# Rails 5: how to run edit.js.erb file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to click a link on my page right after the page finishes loading. That page being on my edit path "/assignments/(id)/edit"

But I'm getting nothing..no console message..no click

I don't think my edit.js.erb file is getting ran and I do not understand why.

App is Rails 5.0.7

Here is what my code looks like...

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Assignment</h1>
<!--go left-->
<%= render 'form', assignment: @assignment %>


<%= link_to 'Show', assignment_path %>|
<%= link_to 'Back', assignments_path %>
```

edit.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#display-contact a').click();
    console.log('It works on each visit!');
});
```

_form.html.erb

```
...
    <div id="display-contact">
      <%= link_to 'Show Contact', contact_path(f.object.contact_id),  remote: true %>
    </div>
...
```

What am I missing / forgetting? How can I get jquery to click this link on pageload?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to delete your `edit.js.erb` file and change your `edit.html.erb` file to:

```
<h1>Editing Assignment</h1>
<!--go left-->
<%= render 'form', assignment: @assignment %>


<%= link_to 'Show', assignment_path %>|
<%= link_to 'Back', assignments_path %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#display-contact a').click();
    console.log('It works on each visit!');
});
</script>
```

Inline javascript though is generally considered bad practice. You should instead put javascript in `.js` files as part of the asset pipeline.